# Android 3 2 1 toast before click - how to implement this in custom camera application

Tags: java, android, camera, click

I want to implement 321 toast that comes before camera clicks an image.Mt Nexus TAB does that but when i click from my application it doesn't.

How can i implement or trigger that?

Comment: I mean the 3 2 1 toast that comes before picture click.

Comment: what is 3 2 1 toast ?

Comment: When we click a picture we can select whether we want a timer 3 2 1 to get ready for the click.. got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // show toast.
    }
}, 1000); // 1000ms delay, you need to make 1 with 1000 1 with 2000 1 with 3000
```

Either do this 3 times or put this code in a simple for loop.

Comment: thanks , but if we want the exact functionality of my tab like not a square box toast but visual 321 and click?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by visual 321? You want it like in the middle of the screen counting down?

Comment: yes, in my tab it says TIMER .. set it to 3s,10s or NULL. Now i have developed an application that automatically click 30 pictures on a socket trigger. I want to start this clicking by letTing user that in 3 seconds we will start clicking pics. Hence i need 3 . 2. 1 and the click 30 images in 30seconds.So how to get that 3 SECONDS TIMER VISUALLY. hOPE I AM CLEAR :)

Comment: You could place an `ImageView` on the middle of the screen and instead of making toasts you could change the `ImageView` and when the countdown is over just hide the `ImageView`. You will have to make some images with 321 but it will look nice.